# Is there a way of accessing maximum redelivery count from a JMS Message?

Tags: java, jms

A simple one.

JMS has a concept of redelivering messages. 
A JMS queue can be configured with a maximum redelivery count after which the message will not be redelivered.

The `javax.jms.Message` interface provides methods to check whether a message is redelivered, and get a current redelivery count.

Is there any way of finding out the **maximum** redelivery count during runtime in a JMS client?

What I am trying to do is to have a method call trigerred on **last** redelivery of a message. I could just have that number configured, but I was wondering if the JMS exposes somewhere this value so that I can lean on it.

Comment: I didn't want to put this as an answer, because it didn't seem helpful, but no (at least not that I'm aware of). A particular JMS provider may provide this data, perhaps on an extension of the Destination interface, but I'm not aware of it from the specification.

Comment: +1. It is helpful. I suspected there's no way of getting that info that way, but I am double checking. Cheers!

Comment: How do you get the current redelivery count? Message interface only exposes a boolean value whether it is currently redelivered.

Comment: for Tibco EMS I do this 
> int deliveryCount = message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
I hear IBM MQ uses the same

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the server side max delivery count configuration from the `message` (javax.jms.Message) object.

However, it is possible to get number of times the current `message` was redelivered:

```
long deliveryCount = message.getLongProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
```